# How to resolve [DataSource.Error] (file in use) for Power Query that only occurs when files are saved in Sharepoint or OneDrive?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery, onedrive

I am encountering an issue where my Power Query fails because I get a message saying that the underlying files are being used by another process. However, this only happens when the documents are saved on SharePoint/OneDrive. When saved on my desktop, the query works whether or not I have the underlying file(s) open.

Very simply speaking, here's my file structure:

Spreadsheet 1.xlsx

Spreadsheet 2.xlsx

Combined.xlsx

All 3 are saved in the same folder. Spreadsheets 1 and 2 have some data. Combined has a query to each of Spreadsheet 1 and Spreadsheet 2, which is then Appended to give a combined overview of the data in Spreadsheets 1 and 2.

When I set this up on my desktop, everything works. I can modify Spreadsheets 1 and 2 whether or not Combined is open, and even if Spreadsheets 1 and 2 are open when Combined is open, the query still works to pull from them when I refresh the data.

However, when I set up the exact same structure on OneDrive and SharePoint (accessed via file explorer), I run into an issue. Specifically, if I attempt to refresh the query data in Combined while either Spreadsheet 1 or 2 is open, I get the following error message:

"[DataSource.Error] The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users[FILEPATH]\Spreadsheet 1.xlsx' because it is being used by another process."

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Again, it works totally fine on my desktop but when I save the files in SharePoint and/or OneDrive folders, I start getting this message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@misk - Have experienced similar issues when working with 'local' files and then switching over to OneDrive/SharePoint.  When the XL file is open as 'local' Power Query can read it fine, when pointing to an open file on OneDrive/SharePoint it cannot read it without barking.

In your situation if you CLOSE both **Spreadsheet 1.xlsx** and **Spreadsheet 2.xlsx** and OPEN **Combined.xlsx** you should find your Power Query inside of **Combined.xlsx** will work fine in both 'local' and OneDrive/SharePoint.

Not the perfect solution, but a workaround at least.